# Shell escape copying out a compiled pdf out of Texshop results in a corrupt version, why?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, shell-escape

I use

`pdflatex --shell-escape -output-directory=tex-aux my-tex-file.tex`

in Texshop to put my aux files inside a folder called `tex-aux` and have the following code in `my-tex-file.tex`:

```
\usepackage{atveryend}
\AtVeryEndDocument{\ShellEscape{cp tex-aux/\jobname.pdf ~/Desktop/folder/}}
```

where the full path of the copied pdf should be `~/Desktop/folder/my-tex-file.pdf`. The pdf inside `~/Desktop/folder/tex-aux/my-tex-file.pdf` works perfectly, but the pdf in `~/Desktop/folder/my-tex-file.pdf` is corrupt and smaller in size. Is there a reason?

Comment: you are copying the file before the tex run has completed and closed the file for writing, that is not going to work.

Comment: `-output-directory` complicates everything, in 30 something years of tex use I don't think I have ever seen a good use for it, but to copy the file, do it externally to tex,, set the command in your editor to be a script that runs pdflatex then copies the file